# Solaris Administration Web GUI?

Tags: web-server, filesystems, solaris, zfs

I recently installed Solaris 11 x86 text install ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen) to be used as a file server running ZFS.

I noticed that I'm given the bare minimum in terms of packages. Is there an official oracle web GUI for managing ZFS? I ran a `netstat` and it doesn't appear to have installed any webserver that's listening. I [saw something from a couple years ago](https://blogs.oracle.com/talley/entry/manage_zfs_from_your_browser), but apparently it's not packaged or maintained anymore

I tried `pkg install` network-console, but it says that *the package isn't available for my platform*.

Any ideas? I'd like to stick with Oracle Solaris instead of the open source alternatives, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you have any options that will drop-in on your existing installation.

For manageability, I'd look at the free or commercial offerings from [Nexenta/NexentaStor](http://nexenta.com/corp/) or [napp-it](http://www.napp-it.de/index_en.html).